# Unable to locate package org.dom4j

Tags: command-line

I tried to install **mulval** and error message is appeared `package org.dom4j does not exist` then I tried to install the package using command `sudo apt-get install -y dom4j` but another message is appeared said U`nable to locate package dom4j`

Comment: *deb* packages are built for specific releases, and you've not told us yours. Are you using a *supported* release which it's built for?  We can't know until you've told us what Ubuntu product & release you're using. I note it's in *universe* for my release (*which may differ to yours*) so do you have *universe* enabled?

Comment: The package you need is: libdom4j-java `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y  libdom4j-java`

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `libdom4j-java`, try to install it with : `sudo apt install libdom4j-java`

Comment: I install it but the problem not solved